Poetry - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named jwt
Added PyJWT pkg to the project but getting error that the module is not found. I added the pkg using the poetry add command from a private repository.
from jwt import decode, get_unverified_header
alg = get_unverified_header(token)["alg"]
decoded_token = decode(token, algorithms=[alg], options={"verify_signature": False})

Tried direct import of jwt.
The pyproject.toml file looks like this
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
streamlit = "1.38.0"
ndg-httpsclient = "^0.5.1"
streamlit-javascript = "^0.1.5"
uuid = "^1.30"
certifi = "2024.7.4"
setuptools = "70.0.0"
idna = "3.7"
pytz = "^2024.1"
pillow = "10.3.0"
pyjwt = "2.8.0"

The lock file looks like this
[[package]]
name = "pyjwt"
version = "2.8.0"
description = "JSON Web Token implementation in Python"
optional = false
python-versions = ">=3.7"
files = [
    {file = "PyJWT-2.8.0-py3-none-any.whl", hash = "sha256:59127c392cc44c2da5bb3192169a91f429924e17aff6534d70fdc02ab3e04320"},
    {file = "PyJWT-2.8.0.tar.gz", hash = "sha256:57e28d156e3d5c10088e0c68abb90bfac3df82b40a71bd0daa20c65ccd5c23de"},
]

[package.extras]
crypto = ["cryptography (>=3.4.0)"]
dev = ["coverage[toml] (==5.0.4)", "cryptography (>=3.4.0)", "pre-commit", "pytest (>=6.0.0,<7.0.0)", "sphinx (>=4.5.0,<5.0.0)", "sphinx-rtd-theme", "zope.interface"]
docs = ["sphinx (>=4.5.0,<5.0.0)", "sphinx-rtd-theme", "zope.interface"]
tests = ["coverage[toml] (==5.0.4)", "pytest (>=6.0.0,<7.0.0)"]

[package.source]
type = "legacy"
url = "https://repo.nexuscloud.aws.rabo.cloud/repository/gr-pypi-13/simple"
reference = "pypi-group"

The dockerfile looks like
FROM <link-to-nexus>/python:3.11.8-slim


WORKDIR /app

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash portal && chown -R portal /home/portal && chown -R portal /app

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./

ARG NEXUSCLOUD_USERNAME
ARG NEXUSCLOUD_PASSWORD

RUN pip config --user set global.index-url "https://$NEXUSCLOUD_USERNAME:$NEXUSCLOUD_PASSWORD@<link-to-nexus>/repository/<repo>/simple"

#Should be same as poetry.lock file
RUN pip install poetry==1.7.1 streamlit==1.38.0 streamlit-javascript==0.1.5 --no-cache-dir

RUN poetry config repositories.pypi-group "https://<link-to-nexus>/repository/<repo>/simple" \
  && poetry config http-basic.pypi-group $NEXUSCLOUD_USERNAME $NEXUSCLOUD_PASSWORD

RUN poetry install --no-cache

COPY . .

ENV ENVIRONMENT=""
ENV BASE_API_URL=$BASE_API_URL

EXPOSE 8501

HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail http://localhost:8501/_stcore/health

ENV PATH=“${PATH}:/root/.local/bin”

USER portal

ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run", "portal/streamlit_app.py", "--server.port=8501", "--server.address=0.0.0.0", "--server.enableXsrfProtection=false", "--server.maxUploadSize=1024", "--client.toolbarMode=minimal", "--client.showErrorDetails=false", "--browser.gatherUsageStats=false"]


The build is successful but on running the app it throws the module not found error.
EDIT: Already checked no dependency confusion with JWT pkg.

it's because you're not running your code in the virtualenv that poetry installed into. See https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#using-your-virtual-environment

@Anentropic so you mean that as per the dockerfile the code is not running inside the virtualenv for poetry in the container? Why I ask this is because all other dependencies works fine inside the container as per the current implementation so whey does a single dependency have an issue.

You install streamlit and streamlit-javascript outside of poetry with the RUN pip install line... I don't know about the other deps but that's probably confusing the issue. If you're going to use Poetry then just pip install poetry and leave the rest to poetry install then run things via the poetry virtualenv
